# unable to unregister phonestatelistener

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to integrate the following into my code to unregister phonestatelistener

```
TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
if(mgr != null) {
    mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE); 
}
```

I have a service which runs in the background and checks if a number is on a blocking list. If yes then it calls `PhonestateListener`

```
TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTM.listen(new phoneStateListener(NumberInbound,Msg_to_display,mTM), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

but when i remove a number from the blocking list I want to unregister `phonestatelistner`. Instead what happens is that `phonestatelistener` is always registered and the msisdn which I previously removed is still blocked !

can you help ?

Code for `phonestatelistner`

```
class phoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    String inbounda;
    int MessagetoDisplay;
    String msg;
    String reply;
    TelephonyManager myt;
    MyService calltoService;
    boolean mBound = false;
    private static final String TAG = "PHONELISTENER";

    phoneStateListener(String inbound,int Message,TelephonyManager t) {
        inbounda = inbound;
        MessagetoDisplay = Message;
        myt = t;
    }

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if(!incomingNumber.equals(inbounda)){

        } else { 

            final String TAG = "Phone call"; 
            ITelephony telephonyService;
        //new code
            Log.v("Phone State", "state:"+state);

            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                   Log.v("Phone State", "incomingNumber:"+incomingNumber+" ended");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Log.v("Phone State", "incomingNumber:"+incomingNumber+" picked up");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if(inbounda.equalsIgnoreCase(incomingNumber)){
                        Log.v("ARE THE SAME...............................", "incomingNumber:"+incomingNumber+ "inbound:"+ inbounda + "MSG TO DISPLAY" +msg);

                        try{
                            Class c = Class.forName(myt.getClass().getName());   
                            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");   
                            m.setAccessible(true);   
                            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(myt);   
                            telephonyService.silenceRinger();   
                            telephonyService.endCall();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try{
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(4000);
                            replyChecker(MessagetoDisplay);
                        } catch(InterruptedException ie){

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public String replyChecker(int Check) {
        SmsManager mySMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
        String destination = inbounda;     
        //open - to be extended to allow user to define own tailored message 
        String Meeting = "Sorry I am at a meeting. Graham  ";
        String Gym = "I am currently at the gym and will respond to you later. Graham ";
        String NewYearsEve = "Happy New Year to you and your loved ones. Graham ";

        if(Check == 1) {
            Log.v("HERE NOW1",":");
            reply  = Meeting;

            mySMS.sendTextMessage(destination, null, Meeting, null, null);
            return reply;
        } else if (Check == 2) {
            Log.v("HERE NOW2",":");
            reply = Gym;
            mySMS.sendTextMessage(destination, null, Gym, null, null);
            return reply;
        } else if (Check == 3) {
            Log.v("HERE NOW3",":");
            reply = NewYearsEve;
            mySMS.sendTextMessage(destination, null, NewYearsEve, null, null);
            return reply;
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return reply;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas ? Seems like phonestatelistener is always listening I cannot unregister it

Comment: What do you mean "the program state is lost" , this doesn't sound like anything to do with Wakelocks?

Comment: Thanks Blundell for answering. I am incorrect about the program state is lost and I have edited my question. What I mean to say is the following, when I have an application with multiple activites and a service and when I navigate between those activities (or the phone sleeps)state information i.e. stored hash data is not referenced anymore. I read that wakelocks or WindowsManager could help in such a situation but I am unclear what the correct way is to proceed here. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I got around this problem by implementing a broadcast receiver in a service. The problem I was facing was not to do with PowerManager, but that the service was not listening for incoming phone calls.

A broadcast receiver listening for android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE done the job

Thanks Graham

Answer (score 1):

> I have multiple activities across my application, and I need a way to keep state in case the phone goes into standby and nativating between activities.

The phone will not go into standby while the user is using your app, and definitely not in between activities, assuming anything vaguely resembling a normal application flow. The device will only fall asleep after inactivity, and when the user taps on something to move from one activity to the next, the inactivity timer resets.

If you wish to keep the device awake while some activity is on the screen, use `android:keepScreenOn` or [`setKeepScreenOn()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29) on some `View`, so you do not have to mess with your own `WakeLock`.